# How to query row containing the given element inside a json column Laravel Postgres

Tags: php, json, postgresql, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Hello all I have a postgresql table that has a json column called agents. See below

```
SELECT agents FROM cnms_rosters;
```

result

```
      agents      
------------------
 [1,13,3,16,15]
 [12,13,14,15,15]
 [11,73,55,16,44]
(3 rows)
```

This column contains the id of an agent. What I want to do is to query the row or rows that has the specific agent id.

How can I achieve that?

I am currently using Laravel Framework is there any eloquent approach in querying the data? if not how to query it using DB::raw or other query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex searching from the model:

```
CnmsRoster::where('agents', '~', "/[^0-9]{$agent_id}[^0-9]/")
```

The `[^0-9]` is intended to match either a square bracket or a comma. This lets you look inside the string for the numeric agent id you want sandwiched between control characters.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

sql query would be using `@>` operator, eg:

```
t=# with cnms_rosters(agents) as (values('[1,13,3,16,15]'::jsonb),('[12,13,14,15,15]'),('[11,73,55,16,44]'))
select agents FROM cnms_rosters where agents @> '[13]'::jsonb;
        agents
----------------------
 [1, 13, 3, 16, 15]
 [12, 13, 14, 15, 15]
(2 rows)
```

or

```
t=# with cnms_rosters(agents) as (values('[1,13,3,16,15]'::jsonb),('[12,13,14,15,15]'),('[11,73,55,16,44]'))
select agents FROM cnms_rosters where agents @> '[16]'::jsonb;
        agents
----------------------
 [1, 13, 3, 16, 15]
 [11, 73, 55, 16, 44]
(2 rows)
```

and same for array:

```
t=# with cnms_rosters(agents) as (values(array[1,13,3,16,15]),(array[12,13,14,15,15]),(array[11,73,55,16,44]))
select agents FROM cnms_rosters where agents @> array[13];
      agents
------------------
 {1,13,3,16,15}
 {12,13,14,15,15}
(2 rows)
```

or

```
t=# with cnms_rosters(agents) as (values(array[1,13,3,16,15]),(array[12,13,14,15,15]),(array[11,73,55,16,44]))
select agents FROM cnms_rosters where agents @> array[16];
      agents
------------------
 {1,13,3,16,15}
 {11,73,55,16,44}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out